# Can't connect to python server on LAN

Tags: python, wireshark, udp, telnet

So I have this python server which just returns the uppercase sentence which came as a input:

```
from socket import *
serverPort = 12000
serverSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)
serverSocket.bind(('192.168.1.2', serverPort))
print "The server is ready to receive on port: {}".format(serverPort)
while 1:
    message, clientAddress = serverSocket.recvfrom(2048)
    print clientAddress, message
    modifiedMessage = message.upper()
    serverSocket.sendto(modifiedMessage, clientAddress)
```

From this client:

```
from socket import *

serverName = "192.168.1.3"
serverPort = 12000
clientSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)
message = raw_input("Input lowercase sentence:")
clientSocket.sendto(message,(serverName, serverPort))
modifiedMessage, serverAddress = clientSocket.recvfrom(2048)
print modifiedMessage
clientSocket.close()
```

Everything works as expected on `localhost` but when I execute `server.py` on one machine and run `client.py` on another machine the client is unable to contact `server.py`. 
 Furthermore I can't even connect to `server.py` via `telnet` on the same machine where `server.py` is running)
Here's the traceback:

```
Connecting To 192.168.1.2...Could not open connection to the host, on port 12000: Connect failed
```

Now I sniffed some packets using Wireshark and surprisingly, the protocol against this packet was `LLC` instead of `UDP`
and the data field was:

```
Data: 74:5f:32:20:61:6e:64:72:6f:69:64
[Length: 11]
```

I apologize if the difference is trivial, but I have just started socket programming and it's bugging me.

Comment: As far as I know, telnet doesn't do UDP. Do you have a firewall running on the server machine?

Comment: @Jukka Nope, I disabled it. I can access Apache server running on the same machine as `server.py` from other clients on LAN

Comment: Are you binding server.py to the appropriate IP address?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, `SOCK_DGRAM` is `UDP` so you won't be able to use `telnet` because it's `TCP` only.

The packets are `UDP`. I expect that `wireshark` is just mistaking them for `LLC` because of the port `12000` (`LLC` runs on top of `UDP` I believe).

It looks like this isn't working because you've set `serverName` to `.3` in the client script but the server is listening on `.2`.

I'll also just ignore the camel casing in Python ;)

Comment: Would you be so kind as to provide me some additional details on this line from your answer: `...LLC runs on top of UDP...` I was under the impression that port `12000` was free?

Comment: Also, it might be a very trivial difference and you might be give yourself a facepalm when you read it, but, if I am not wrong, I am not following the HTTP protocol, right? But there is a request response cycle?

Comment: HTTP is quite different; it's a higher level protocol built on top of TCP.

What you're doing is simple `request` -> `response` but over raw UDP.

As for the ports, you're free to use any port that you like - just `wireshark` seems to think that `LLC` often uses that port... Actually it's assigned to an IBM protocol which you'll see here: https://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/service-names-port-numbers.txt